# libtiff check failed when trying to build a library that depends on it

Tags: cmake, libtiff

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I have `libtiff5` installed (using `sudo apt install libtiff5`). When trying to build a library that depends on libtiff I get the following error:

```
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
configure: error: libtiff check failed
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? My guess is I have to modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I don't know where `apt` installed `libtiff`

Comment: As usual, for build a project which uses a library, you need `-dev` package of that library.

Comment: That worked, thanks! If you add an answer I will accept it.